# What is bandwidth of a resistor

Tags: noise, microwave

I am reading the book "Microwave Engineering" from Pozar Chapter Noise and Nonlinear Distortion.

Pn noise power from the circuit can be described as the following formula. Pn depends on B, where B is bandwidth. The bandwidth of the resistor should be infinite because every frequency can pass through. Then noise power will be infinite. I don't think noise power can be infinite. I wanted to know where the problem was.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I imagine the bandwidth is referring to the bandwidth of the bandpass filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resistor must have a dielectric around it and a path length and thus Cp in fF or pF over a ground plane and ESL in nH/mm effective series inductance.

Thus it will have a bandwidth that depends on the transmission line properties of the geometry.

This is why Network Analyzer 50 ohm calibrators are [very expensive due to the ppm geometric machined enclosure.](https://www.testequity.com/product/25998-1-85561A?srsltid=AdGWZVRuKXDI7-szSxCkuA07epQeajXu2QRGytdh0Cmr7LNZkSdEBpe2IWQ)

But for this example it is dependent on B of the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor bandwidth is infinite, but the noise power formula is a linear approximation of an actually exponential term with a finite integral.

For microwave, there may be a point in getting back to the proper formula, but at that kind of wavelength, the resistor will not be behaving ideally for a number of other reasons.

I am not sure just at what kind of wavelength the noise power formula stops being a useful approximation, but it's fine for most normal electronic uses.